# Unable to modify Python List in-place from within Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, in-place

We have a function `rotate()` that takes a list `nums` and modifies it in-place. However I am unable to get the correctly modified list from after the `rotate()` function call.

Why is this happening?

```
def rotate(nums, k):
    """
    Rotate the list to the right by k steps
    Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
    """

    # Reverse
    nums.reverse()
    a = nums[:k]
    a.reverse()
    b = nums[-(len(nums)-k):]
    b.reverse()
    nums = a + b
    print('Inside function:', nums)

nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
rotate(nums, 3)
print('Outside function: ', nums)
```

**Output**

```
Inside function: [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
Outside function:  [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]   <--- incorrect!
```

Comment: coz you just reassigned `nums` (nums = a + b) and that's not in-place modification

Comment: do `nums[:] = a + b` instead

Comment: You don't have a inplace operation, because you generate a new list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line:

```
nums = a + b
```

Creates a new local variable `nums` in the scope of your `rotate` function. To modify the list as passed in, you can change that line to the following:

```
nums[:] = a + b
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use inplace-methods on your list, e.g. `del` and `extend`:

```
def rotate(nums, k):
    a = nums[:-k]
    del nums[:-k]
    nums.extend(a)
```